# Mapping 2 tables into 1 domain with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, mapping

I'm trying to do a complicated thing for me with Hibernate. I will explain it:

I have 2 tables. 3 of the columns of each tables are the same (i mean, same value) but have different names. Example:

```
Table1 (name, tour, year, column1, column2, ...) and PK is (name, tour, year)

Table2 (name_aux, tour_aux, year_aux, column3, column4, ...) and PK is (name_aux, tour_aux, year_aux)
```

So, I want to transform these 2 tables into 1 domain object in Hibernate. I read that there is a @SecondayTable annotation but I think isn't that I want. Also I don't know if this is possible. At the moment I have 2 domain objects mapping these 2 tables with their @EmbeddedId cause the composite PK.

The result of the domain object should be a class with these attributes:

```
name (or name_aux)
year (or as year_aux)
tour (or tour_aux)
column1
column2
column3
column4
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two tables with data of 3 columns same but, the column names are differant for the same 3 columns?

You can use @Embedded for using the same object for two diff domain objects, at the same time you can override the column name by using the property @AttributeOverride

check this here http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/

Comment: That's the problem, yes. I'm reading about the @AttributeOverride and I think it could be OK for me. Thanks!!